# Distinguish between two instances of the same AWS lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-go

I need to uniquely identify the message I'm sending from the lambda to some consumer. What unique information can I utilize to create the unique ID for each message I'm sending out?

- I can send few messages per request (lambda run)
- I can have few instances of the
  same lambda running and sending different messages at the same time

The message I'm processing has the unique ID, but it can be changed during the flow.

GoLang, if it matters.

Comment: [`AwsRequestID`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model-context.html) from the context object, perhaps?  This ID should match what's written to the Lambda logs, though I haven't worked with Go.  You might look into that and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I have understood your exact problem.
You can just generate your own unique ID for each message. If you want to link it to each lambda execution, you can do it using AwsRequestID of the context.
Take in account that the same ID is given when your Lambda is retried (it’s like an identity of the trigger that caused this execution).